# Create to database using web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to insert a new entry in my database using web api. I have two web projects: one is a UI project where all the user interaction will occur and the other is a services project which will handle all interactions with my database.

Below is my post method that will take in form data for creating a new team.

```
// POST: Api/Team/Create
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(Team team)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        HttpEndPointContext httpEndPoint = new HttpEndPointContext()
                        {
                            AuthenticationMethod = HttpAuthenticationMethods.None,
                            Ssl = false,
                            HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
                            Path = "localhost:32173/api/team/",
                            QueryStrings = null,
                            PayloadData = SerializationHelper.Current.Serialize(team.ToString(), SerializationTypes.Xml)
                        };

                        IProcessResult result = HttpConnectionManager.Current.SendMessage(httpEndPoint);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
```

And this is my method for dealing with my PayloadStream/PayloadData attribute in the above method:

```
private void StreamPayload(HttpWebRequest webRequest, HttpEndPointContext httpEndPointContext)
        {
            if (httpEndPointContext.HttpMethod == new HttpMethod("GET"))
                return;
            //TODO: FIX MAYBE .... sometimes we want to post body with GET.

            //Stream vs string
            if (httpEndPointContext.PayloadStream == null)
            {
                //Wrap with SOAP Envelope and method if defined in SoapDefinition
                string data = httpEndPointContext.PayloadData ?? String.Empty;

                if (httpEndPointContext.SoapDefinition != null)
                {
                    //If parameters is set, clear existing payload data.
                    data = String.Empty;

                    if (httpEndPointContext.SoapDefinition.Parameters != null)
                        foreach (var parameter in httpEndPointContext.SoapDefinition.Parameters)
                        {
                            data += String.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                        }

                    data = String.Format("<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" +
                                    "<s:Body><{0} xmlns='{2}'>" +
                                     "{1}</{0}></s:Body></s:Envelope>",
                                     httpEndPointContext.SoapDefinition.SoapMethod, data,httpEndPointContext.SoapDefinition.SoapGlobalKey);
                }

                byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

                httpEndPointContext.PayloadStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            }

            using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                StreamHelper.Current.CopyStreams(httpEndPointContext.PayloadStream, requestStream);

                requestStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

And the code for getting the server response. I'm currently getting an Internal Server (500) Error. Not sure why.

```
public IProcessResult SendMessage(HttpEndPointContext httpEndPointContext)
            { 
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(httpEndPointContext);

                StreamPayload(webRequest, httpEndPointContext);

                IProcessResult result = GetWebResponse(webRequest, httpEndPointContext);

                return result;
            }

            private IProcessResult GetWebResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest, HttpEndPointContext httpEndPointContext)
            {
                //Get Response
                WebResponse response;

                IProcessResult result = new ProcessResult(Statuses.Success);

                try
                {
                    response = webRequest.GetResponse();
                }
                catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
                {
                    //Do exception handling. Still get the response for 500s etc.
                    result.Error.Exception = ex;
                    result.Status = Constants.Statuses.FailedUnknown;
                    result.ResponseCodeDescription = ex.Status.ToString();
                    result.ResponseCode = ex.Status.ToString();
                    result.Error.ErrorCode = ex.Status.ToString();

                    response = ex.Response;

                    //The error did not have any response, such as DNS lookup.
                    if (response == null)
                        return result;
                }

                try
                {
                    //Get the response stream.
                    Stream responseData = response.GetResponseStream();

                    if (responseData == null)
                        throw new CoreException("No Response Data in GetWebResponse.",
                            "No Response Data in GetWebResponse. EndPoint:{0}", httpEndPointContext.ToString());

                    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                    var reader = new StreamReader(responseData);

                    // Read the content.
                    result.ResponseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                finally
                {
                    response.Close();
                }

                result.ResponseCode = ((int)((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode).ToString();
                result.ResponseCodeDescription = ((HttpWebResponse) response).StatusDescription;

                return result;
            }
```

And finally, my method for inserting to the database, found in my services project:

```
//POST api/controller/5
        public IProcessResult Insert(Team team)
        {
            return TeamBusinessManager.Current.Insert(SecurityManager.Current.ConnectionContext, new Team());
        }
```

I'm confused as to why I'm getting the 500 error. I'm not sure if it's the PayloadData attribute in my POST method or is it something wrong with my method in my services project.

Comment: Is this in development or production. Ie. are you getting the error in VS or only in production?

Comment: This project is still in the development phase. I'm working with Visual Studio.

Comment: And you not hitting a break point in the web api controller?

Comment: That's the funny thing. I tried to see if the api controller was even being referenced in the first place and it isn't. I tested this theory on the GET method of my api controller. I never hit a break point when trying to retrieve data from the database, yet if I comment out the method in my api controller, exceptions are thrown for a missing provider section in my app.config so I just leave it as is. In my mind, it seems as if the app just "knows" to use the api controller methods without being referenced anywhere in the project.